# Opening and executing a batch file which is saved in the application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I wrote a batch file, which is stored in my controller, which should write to a .bat file in the public folder.

The code is:

```
def checkin
    file_path = "#{Rails.root}/public/batfiles/#{Time.now.hour}_#{Time.now.min}_#   {Time.now.sec}.bat"
    file = File.new(file_path, 'w')
    svn_path = params[:svn_path]
    content = ''
    content += "@echo off\n"
    content += "echo.\n"
    content += "echo. [ SVN Updater ]\n"
    content += "set SVNURL=#{svn_path}\n"
    content += "set SOURCE=C:\\Users\\"
    content += "set SVN=C:\\Program Files\\TortoiseSVN\\bin\n"
    content += "echo.\n"
    content += '"%SVN%\TortoiseProc.exe" /command:checkout /path:"%SOURCE%" /url:%SVNURL% /closeonend:2'
    content += "echo. done.\n"
    content += "echo.\n"
    content += "echo. Operation complete.\n"
    file.write content
    file.close
    send_file(file.path)
  end
```

When I save the file in public/batfiles/.bat, I want to run the file not on the server but on the user's system.

Right now the user downloads the .bat file and runs it from the browser. Instead, I want the user to do nothing but have the application open his .bat file and run it in his local machine.

Comment: What you want was the basis for all sorts of security and data-privacy issues many years ago, and was removed from browsers as a result. I'm not sure you could do it "automatically" without some client-side plug-in or app receiving the file, or the user allowing it.

Comment: @Tin Man - Thanks for the info. But cant't we use javascript or any other client side scripting to open the downloaded file and execute it from the stored location?